# Ordered list issue :How to add background color to each li in the ordered list?

Tags: css

[image]

How do I move the number inside the background colors as shown in the above image?

Can someone show me a working  example?

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dev1212/UAack/)

CSS

```
goals-list1 {
    padding-left:10px
}
.goals-list1 ol {
    border:0px solid red;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.goals-list1 ul {
    border:0px solid red;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.goals-list1 li {
    border:0px solid blue;
    color:#666666;
}
.goals-list1 .pink {
    color:#FF1493;
}
.goals-list1 .violet {
    color:#9400D3;
}
.goals-list1 .orange {
    color:#FFA500;
}
ol .goals-info {
    ;
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<ol  class="goals-list1">
    <li class="pink goals-info">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>Lifestyle</li>
            <li>son</li>
            <li>Inflation</li>
            <li>Aug 2012</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="pink goals-info">
        <ul class="list-unstyled ">
            <li>Lifestyle</li>
            <li>son</li>
            <li>Inflation</li>
            <li>Aug 2012</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
ol {list-style-position: inside;}
```

but there will be a little bit of extra rejigging of the `ul`'s padding etc. after that.

Comment: how can i fix the extra rejigging so that it show up like the image?

Answer (score 0):

add a background color to the ol element itself:

```
.goals-list1 ol{background-color:blue;}
```